# Can´t use array data json in cakephp

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, cakephp

I´m trying to read JSON information in the response JS. I have data but I can´t read it
I see in debug mode my array

> (datos) -- "{"mensaje":"Ya has votado este video","estado":"0"}"

, but `alert(datos.mensaje)` or `alert(datos.estado)` is empty...

In my view use `echo json_encode($data);` and dataType in call Ajax is json and Type is Post

With `JSON.stringify(datos)`, I am getting:

```
"{\"mensaje\":\"Ya has votado este video\",\"estado\":\"0\"}"
```

I want to use `datos.mensaje`

Regards

Comment: you are missing a semicolon on line 56 of that view. Wait, no? Mmm, maybe if you post some code we can guess better.

Comment: Can you post a pic about how your data is being returned...like a console.log(datos) or something

Comment: data returns me all the html

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a guess what you're trying to say, but as far I can see you're trying to encode a given JSON string. Try using json_decode in your view:

echo json_decode($data);

https://www.php.net/json_decode